# @GetMapping and @GetMapping("/{id}") always return @GetMapping("/{id}")

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two methods @GetMapping and @GetMapping("/{id}")

```
@RestController("/user"){
public class UserRestController {

@GetMapping
public ResponseData get() {
      ...........
    return responseData;
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseData getUser(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
    ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();
      ...........
    return responseData;
}
```

When I hit a URL *`http://localhost:8080/user`* I took I @GetMapping("/{id}") method 
because it takes `id` null, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: `id` is Long but you are passing `user` which is not a long.

Comment: I edit my code, a user is a super path request

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mixing up `PathParam` with `PathVariable`.

In your example, I think what you need is the [`PathVariable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html). Moreover, you can remove the `name` field, since the parameter's name is the same: `id`.

Here's the updated code:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseData getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
   ...
}
```

Also, what you are looking for to define your `user` mappings under the same controller, is the [`RequestMapping`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping) annotation:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserRestController {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this method

```
@GetMapping("/")
public ResponseData getUser(@RequestParam Long id)
{
  ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();

  //.......

  return responseData;
}
```